# Как определить что элемент принадлежит Node коллекции

Tags: javascript, массивы, коллекции, динамические-массивы

[image: вот скриншот что пытаюсь сделать: клик вне окошка - дожен привести к его закрытию, а колличество узлов в окошке в дальнейшем может меняться]Всем добрового времени суток! Вопрос бесконечно тупой но все же. Пишу модальное окно и хочу реализовать такую фичу: клик вне модального окна = закрытие модального окна. Идея с созданием подложки которая затемняет весь document пока модальное окно активно - не подходит (хотя пока я так и оставил что в качестве event.target у меня элемент, содержай класс "modalWrap). Но тут есть загвоздка - она может быть а может и не быть. Так же не хотелось бы каждому дочернему узлу добавлять какой-то класс - если узлов будет 1000 - то придется вручную потом добавить каждому элементу такой класс.

вот так выглядит разметка:

```
<div class="modalWrap">
  <div attr="modal">
    <button>
      <span></span><span></span>
    </button>
    <div class="modal__header">
      <h2 class="modal__title">h2 modalOne title text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__content someRandomClass">
      <h3>custom title of modalOne</h3>
    </div>
    <div>hello from modalOne's footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

вот такие потуги я делал относительно JS :

```
modalWrap.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
const window = modal.querySelector([attr="modal"]) //возвращает колекцию
   if (event.target == !modal || event.target == ! window.children) {  //понятно что здесь я буквально сравниваю один клик аж с 4ю разными DOM элементами, т.е. чтобы условие было правдиво - надо чтобы клик произошел аж на 4х элементах что конечно бред
   closeModal();
   }
}
```

и вот вопрос можно ли как-то проверить что event.target = любой (один из) дочерний элемент div с атрибутом attr="modal". я уж и через цикл пытался сделать - все равно какая то лажа. То есть коротко: клик вне div attr="modal" и не на его дочерних - должен привести к закрытию этого окна (вызов ф-й close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. [события всплывают](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing), мы можем воспользоваться этим и отслеживать:

```js
const mod = document.getElementById('modal');
const close = document.getElementById('close');
// Вешаем обработчик открытия
document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', () => {
  mod.style.display = 'block'; // Показываем "модалку"
  // Вешаем обработчики клика
  mod.addEventListener('click', inClick);
  document.addEventListener('click', outClick);
  close.addEventListener('click', outClick);
})

function inClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // Если внутри жмякнули, ничего не делать
}

function outClick(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'open') {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Если это кнопка открытия, не реагировать
    return;
  }
  mod.style.display = 'none';
  mod.removeEventListener('click', inClick);
  document.removeEventListener('click', outClick);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px">Допустим, тут что есть</div>
<hr />
<div id="modal" style="display: none">
  <div><input /></div>
  <div><input /></div>
  <div><input /></div>
  <button id="close">закрыть</button>
</div>
<hr />
<button id="open">открыть</button>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px">И тут тоже</div>
<hr />
```

Что происходит в скрипте: При открытии модалки, вешаем обработчик клика на форму и на **document**.

Когда клик произошел, если он всплыл до формы, значит ткнули в форме и закрывать не надо, останавливаем всплытие **e.stopPropagation()**.

Если событие всплыло наверх до **document**, значит жмякнули мимо модалки и надо закрыть ее, удалив обработчики.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь. Хотя я и не хотел пере*бывать хоистинг но похоже что это единственный способ. благодраю за подсказку

Answer (score 0):

Удобнее всего на мой вкус превратить коллекцию в массив и воспользоваться include, примерно так:

[...коллекция].includes(event target)

Чтобы избавиться от подложки, вы можете сделать глобальный обработчик клика, повесить его прямо на document и в нем проверять, есть ли модалка в цепочке родителей event.target. Если нет и модалка существует - закрываем.

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ, но кажись это не работает:   ` const window = Array.from(modal.firstChild.childNodes);
    console.log(window);
    modal.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (window.includes(event.target)) {
        console.log('click');
      }
    });`    - если я правильно понял. у меня при клике по последнему элементу вывод в консоль происходит а по остальным нет. к тому же метод includes проверяет массив на какой-то конкретный элемент - а для меня не имеет значения "какой" - мне важно что клик по модалке или по ее содержимому не должен приводить к закрытию

Comment: т.е вот например https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from и метод возвращает true/false в зависимости от условий, а для меня это не имеет значения в этой задачке. клик по любому из узлов самого модального окна не должен привести к закрытию окна. я уж и через getElementsByTagNames получал коллекцию . неужели здесь вручную перечислять каждый modal[i] - это ж брет